# How Can I Protect My C# Code From Being Decompiled?

Tags: c#, decompiler, piracy-prevention

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.Net Obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988451/net-obfuscation)
>   [Alternative for Obfuscation in the .NET world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204076/alternative-for-obfuscation-in-the-net-world)

Just a few minutes ago, I read that there are a number of tools, many free, that allow you to convert a C# .exe back to a VB solution. This means that my proprietary code can be viewed, edited, and recompiled/redistributed. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short you need to use [Obfuscation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation). To name a few.

1. [Dotfuscator](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview)
2. [Obfuscator](http://www.secureteam.net/Obfuscator.aspx)
3. [Skater](http://www.rustemsoft.com/freeware_obfuscator.htm) (Freeware)
4. [DeployLX CodeVeil](http://xheo.com/products/code-protection)
5. Plus Visual Studio comes with a light version of Dotfuscator.

You can read this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164058.aspx) that has advice on how to obfuscate your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will look into both. (Edit: I will look into all 4.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Obfuscator.. [Salamander](http://www.remotesoft.com/salamander/obfuscator.html) is one such tool for .NET...

[Confuser](http://confuser.codeplex.com/) is another free obfuscator for .NET. It is developed in C# and using Mono

Answer (score 0):

You can use mono to compile it to a native binary, just google it up.

Answer (score 0):

You could also code the sensitive functions/components into native C++, wrap it in C++/CLI and use with .NET in addition to obfuscating your .NET assemblies.

Even with obfuscation the JIT compiler will need to see the IL code eventually, you are just making it more difficult to decompile.

Answer (score 0):

An obfuscator is a good bet, as it *increases* a person's effort to view, edit, redistribute, etc. the code.

While these don't protect your code physically they could prevent the behavior of decompiling your code: legal mechanisms such as patents, copyrights, and licenses.

Decompiling or reverse engineering is a battle of economic efforts. Is it worth it for you to obfuscate your code (potentially running afoul of reflection "gotchas") vs. is it worth it for someone to reverse engineer (with little context) instead of emulating or rewriting?

A comment on this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/1988467/64348, with which several agree, indicates that obfuscation does not *prevent* getting back to the original (or some close enough version of the original) code. Obfuscation is just a stand-in to a reversible translation with no real key needed except some useful context.

Comment: Don't you mean it *increases* the effort required?

Comment: @Ben, oops yes. Maximizes the other party's effort, minimizing their gain by decompiling.

Comment: @Matt - np. I used to worry about this a little too much, but the legal folks are way more versed than us techies!