# Code Security for .net other than using obfuscation

Tags: .net

Is there any way to prevent the code from being dissembled other then obfuscation.

Comment: Your question seems to be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204076/alternative-for-obfuscation-in-the-net-world

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent your code from being disassembled!

The runtime needs to be able to execute the instructions that you have created with your code otherwise your software won't run. If the computer that the software is running on can read the instructions then a user who has control of that computer can get access to the instructions and by way of decompilation recreate a version of the code - it may not look exactly like the original code but will compile to an equivalent program.

There are however several approaches for hiding the instructions and the structure of your code from prying eyes - one of them being obfuscation. Ultimately they are only speed bumps as a competent hacker could copy your instructions out from the machine's memory as the software is executed...